# Which is the easiest way to write this PHP code with Python syntax?

Tags: php, python, python-3.x

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php

$result = [];

$input = ['Sofia 50', 'Sofia 20', 'Sofia 30', 'Varna 10', 'Varna 20'];

foreach ($input as $item) {
    $keyValuePairs = explode(' ', $item);
    $key = $keyValuePairs[0];
    $value = $keyValuePairs[1];
    if (array_key_exists($key, $result)) {
        $result[$key]['count'] += 1;
        $result[$key]['sum'] += $value;
    } else {
        $result[$key]['count'] = 1;
        $result[$key]['sum'] = $value;
    }
}

echo '<pre>';
var_dump($result);
```

**What I tried in Python:**

```
input_row = input_row.split(' ')
region_name = input_row[0]
region_size = input_row[1]

if region_name in result:
    result[region_name]['count'] += 1
    result[region_name]['sum'] += region_size
else:
    result[region_name]['count'] = 1
    result[region_name]['sum'] = region_size
```

*But it doesn't work in Python.*

What result I expect:

```
array(2) {
  ["Sofia"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(3)
    ["sum"]=>
    int(100)
  }
  ["Varna"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["count"]=>
    int(2)
    ["sum"]=>
    int(30)
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you explain what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: @Austin Sure, it's edited.

Comment: No loop in your python code makes it a bit suspect... what is `input_row` there?

Comment: Your Python code would work if you initialize the region name dictionary in your else statement first: `else: result[region_name] = {}; result[region_name]['count'] = 1` etc.

Comment: @ViktorPetrov Hmm, yeah, you are right, but why thix syntax, doesn't work `result[region_name]['count'] = 1`

Comment: Because you never declared/initialized `result[region_name]`

Comment: @MorganFreeFarm because `result[region_name]` is not declared as a dictionary to begin with. The logic is dict -> key -> value, what you were trying to do is  dict1 -> key -> dict2 -> key -> value without having initialized dict2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHP to Python

```
input_data = ['Sofia 50', 'Sofia 20', 'Sofia 30', 'Varna 10', 'Varna 20']
result = {}

for elem in input_data:                     #Iterate each element. 
    key, value = elem.split()               #Split on space
    if key not in result:                   #Check if key exists in result
        result[key] = {'count': 0,'sum': 0}
    result[key]['count'] += 1                #Increment count
    result[key]['sum'] += int(value)         #Increment value

print(result)
```

**Output:**

```
{'Sofia': {'count': 3, 'sum': 100}, 'Varna': {'count': 2, 'sum': 30}}
```